# Bootstrap dropdown items with multiple links inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Because Bootstrap dropdown items have this structure:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="linkt/to/item1">Item1</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's not possible to put a text with multiple linked words in the same item. Something like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>This <a href="linkt/to/item1">Item</a> 
        is a part of <a href="linkt/to/page1">Page1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any other option to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<li>` content into `<span>`'s :

```html
<li><span>This <a href="linkt/to/item1">Item</a> 
    is a part of <a href="linkt/to/page1">Page1</a>
</span></li>
```

and add the below CSS to prevent wordwrapping :

```css
.dropdown-menu li span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

the padding is just for the eyes :) demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/prw73rL9/**